# Accessing Panda's DataFrame Columns Based on Condition to Derive Results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, conditional-statements

I want to pass my predictive model values that will be extracted from Pandas DataFrame based on condition and results from models will be placed in Pandas DataFrame.

**DataFrame**

```
+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+
|    Date    | Actual Value | Prediction | Model Values |
+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+
| 02/01/2021 |         0.02 |            |              |
| 03/01/2021 |         0.06 |            |              |
| 04/01/2021 |         0.02 |            |              |
| 05/01/2021 |         0.04 |            |              |
| 06/01/2021 |         0.04 |            |              |
| 07/01/2021 |         0.08 |            |              |
| 08/01/2021 |         0.06 |            |              |
| 09/01/2021 |         0.02 |       0.03 |         0.03 |
| 10/01/2021 |         0.20 |            |              |
| 11/01/2021 |         0.02 |            |              |
| 12/01/2021 |         0.02 |            |              |
| 13/01/2021 |         0.09 |       0.06 |         0.06 |
| 14/01/2021 |         0.06 |            |              |
| 15/01/2021 |         0.04 |            |              |
| 16/01/2021 |         0.06 |            |              |
| 17/01/2021 |         0.03 |       0.04 |         0.04 |
| 18/01/2021 |         0.03 |            |              |
| 19/01/2021 |         0.06 |            |              |
| 20/01/2021 |         0.06 |            |              |
+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+
```

`Actual Value` is the actual value for the particular date.
`Prediction` is the predicted value for that date. (needs to populated)
`Model Values` the value that needs to be passed to model to get results. (the tricky part)

The model takes past 7 days values and gives next day's output. Hence the minimum date on which a prediction can be made is `9th Jan`.
To make prediction for `9th Jan` `df['Actual Value'].iloc[:7,]` will be passed to the model which will output numpy (1*1) array. The value is then placed in column `Prediction`. (i.e. 0.03)

**The part where I am stuck**

I want to use the predicted value on `9th Jan` and past 6 values to make prediction for `10th Jan`.  Which means `df['Actual Value'].iloc[1:7,:]`  + `df['Prediction'].iloc[7,:]`.

I want to access these values and pass it to model which will give a result numpy (1*1) array that needs to be placed in column `Prediction` on `Date` `10th Jan`.

Now that we have value for `10th Jan` we can make prediction for `11th Jan` based on similar logic use `df['Actual Value'].iloc[2:7,:]`  + `df['Prediction'].iloc[7:9,:]`. Pass these values to model and get result for `11th Jan`.

Similar process to be followed for predicting `12th Jan`.

But for `13th Jan` we will use `Actual Value` for last 7 days to get `Prediction`. This part is already done. There will always be a value after every 4 days on 09th, 13th and 17th. The code to do that is as follows:

```
look_back = 7
look_forward = 1
n_days_pred = 4
pred = 0
predictions = []
while pred <= X_test.shape[0]:
    predictions.append(model.predict(X_test[pred].reshape(1, look_back, look_forward)).flatten().tolist())
    pred = pred + n_days_pred
predictions_flat = [item for sublist in predictions for item in sublist]
start_date = test_df.Date.min() + dt.timedelta(look_back)
predictions_df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start=start_date, periods=len(predictions), freq='4D'))
predictions_df['Prediction'] = predictions_flat

# Join predictions_df with df 
df = analysis_df.set_index('Date').join(predictions_df)
```

`df` from code above is same as shown above.

I am stuck at how to access the values form column `Actual Value` & `Prediction` to get predictions for 10th, 11th, 12th, 14th, 15th, 16th, 18th, 19th and 20th.

Comment: Not sure I’m understanding this right, 1) your inputs are from `prediction` unless it’s not available, then you use `actual value`, and 2) you need the last 7 days to make a prediction. Is that right or am I missing something ?

Comment: @Cimbali point 2 is correct. point 1) only `actual value`  will be used after every 4 days so for `9th, 13th and 17th` only `actual value` will be used to make prediction (this is done and is already in `df`) to populate `Prediction` for `10th` , `Prediction` of `9th` and actual values from`3rd to 8th` will be used as model requires at least 7 values. Similarly to populate prediction for `11th` `Prediction` of  `9th & 10th` along with `Actual Value` `4th to 8th` will be used.

Comment: So at some point (9th + 7days I guess, so starting from the 16th?) only `prediction` values will be used, is that correct ?

Comment: @Cimbali  to populate prediction for 16th `Prediction` from 13th, 14th and 15th will be used along with `Actual Value` of 9th, 10th, 11th & 12th will be used. The idea is to make prediction for the next 4 days. So if I am at 13th and I need to make prediction for 13th, 14th, 15th and 16th. I will use `Actual Value` from 6th - 12th to predict 13th. To make prediction for 14th I will use 7th - 12th `Actual Value` and predicted value of 13th. Similarly to make prediction for 15th I will use 8th -12th `Actual Value` and 13th and 14th `Predicted` value.

Comment: @Cimbali there won't be any case where only `Predicted` is used to make next day prediction. Because only max of 4 days is being predicted. So at the 4th day you would still have 4 Actual + 3 Predicted values (total: 7) to make a prediction for 4th day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let’s use the dates to index the dataframe rather than indices.

```py
df = df.set_index('date')
```

Now computing your every-4-days computation

```py
n_days_pred = 4
look_back = 7

for model_start_date in df.index[look_back::n_days_pred]:
    for predict_date in pd.date_range(model_start_date, periods=n_days_pred, freq='D'):
 
        model_input = pd.concat([
           # All actual values before model_start_date
            df.loc[predict_date - pd.Timedelta(days=look_back):model_start_date - pd.Timedelta(days=1), 'actual value'],

            # All predictions since model_start_date
            df.loc[model_start_date:predict_date - pd.Timedelta(days=1), 'prediction'],
        ])
        df.loc[predict_date, 'prediction'] = model.predict( .... model_input .... )
```

If I fill `prediction` with only the word `pred` and `actual value` with only the word `val` and then print `model_input` from that loop, here is what I get:

```
2021-01-02    val
2021-01-03    val
2021-01-04    val
2021-01-05    val
2021-01-06    val
2021-01-07    val
2021-01-08    val
Freq: D, dtype: object
2021-01-03     val
2021-01-04     val
2021-01-05     val
2021-01-06     val
2021-01-07     val
2021-01-08     val
2021-01-09    pred
Freq: D, dtype: object
2021-01-04     val
2021-01-05     val
2021-01-06     val
2021-01-07     val
2021-01-08     val
2021-01-09    pred
2021-01-10    pred
Freq: D, dtype: object
2021-01-05     val
2021-01-06     val
2021-01-07     val
2021-01-08     val
2021-01-09    pred
2021-01-10    pred
2021-01-11    pred
Freq: D, dtype: object
2021-01-06    val
2021-01-07    val
2021-01-08    val
2021-01-09    val
2021-01-10    val
2021-01-11    val
2021-01-12    val
Freq: D, dtype: object
2021-01-07     val
2021-01-08     val
2021-01-09     val
2021-01-10     val
2021-01-11     val
2021-01-12     val
2021-01-13    pred
Freq: D, dtype: object
2021-01-08     val
2021-01-09     val
2021-01-10     val
2021-01-11     val
2021-01-12     val
2021-01-13    pred
2021-01-14    pred
Freq: D, dtype: object
2021-01-09     val
2021-01-10     val
2021-01-11     val
2021-01-12     val
2021-01-13    pred
2021-01-14    pred
2021-01-15    pred
Freq: D, dtype: object
2021-01-10    val
2021-01-11    val
2021-01-12    val
2021-01-13    val
2021-01-14    val
2021-01-15    val
2021-01-16    val
Freq: D, dtype: object
2021-01-11     val
2021-01-12     val
2021-01-13     val
2021-01-14     val
2021-01-15     val
2021-01-16     val
2021-01-17    pred
Freq: D, dtype: object
2021-01-12     val
2021-01-13     val
2021-01-14     val
2021-01-15     val
2021-01-16     val
2021-01-17    pred
2021-01-18    pred
Freq: D, dtype: object
2021-01-13     val
2021-01-14     val
2021-01-15     val
2021-01-16     val
2021-01-17    pred
2021-01-18    pred
2021-01-19    pred
Freq: D, dtype: object
```

Where `df` is

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'prediction': 'pred', 'actual value': 'val'}, index=pd.date_range('2021-01-02', '2021-01-20', freq='D'))
```

As you can see it’s between 0 and 3 latest `pred` (with the dates in the index), then before that `val` − and always 7 entries. I don’t think you can do much smarter than a loop, since you’re computing the inputs of the next iterations as you go.

Comment: The answer is correct. but I am confused on line `df.loc[predict_date] = model.predict( .... model_input .... )` shouldn't we specify the column name to replace value? I think it should be `df.loc[predict_date,'Prediction'] = model.predict( .... model_input .... )`